# HTML5 Canvas color help

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Hi I have this simple array inside my variable with some colors

```
var clr = ['#FF0000', '#0000FF', '#FFFF00', '#008000', '#FFA500', '#800080', '#ffffff'];
```

and then a function which should return one of those values in single quotes

```
function colors() {
    var color;
    color = "'";
    color += Math.floor(Math.random() * clr.length);
    color += "'";
    return color;
}
```

this function is then called to show various colored balls

```
function CreateBall(x, y, vx, vy, r, s) {
    this.color = colors();
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.vx = vx;
    this.vy = vy;
    this.r = r;
    this.size = s;
}
```

However it doesn't work? Any ideas why?

To see the full code, please look at the source here: http://dev.driz.co.uk/pool

Comment: I suggest you to use [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843 "Firebug")

Comment: Firebug says what I thought the error was, something to do with an incorrect string where the color is used in the gradient. But what though? I've tried the answer below but it doesn't seem to have fixed it. Any ideas? I think it's something to do with the quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should fix your problem

```
function colors() {
    return clr[Math.floor(Math.random() * clr.length)];
}
```

### [Demo](http://jsbin.com/ejibo4/2)

Comment: Cool. So what was the problem then? What was the function returning prior to adding in the clr[] part? Thanks again.

Comment: Actually another quick question. How would I make it so their was an equal number of each color, would that be a big job or relatively easy to implement, just noticed that some colors and being generated too many times making it look odd.

Comment: `clr[]` is an array, right ?? we are returning the array value(color).. since we are using a random function, it might be difficult to generate exact number(But I won't say it is Impossible).

Answer (score 4):

At the moment, the value returned from `colors()` is a string that looks something like `"'#ffffff'"`.  When this colour value is actually applied a syntax error is thrown on the following line:

> `122: gradient.addColorStop(.85, ball[i].color);`

This is likely to be caused by the single quotes you're wrapping around to your returned colour — you don't need to do this since it's already a string value.  You also never actually pluck the values out of your array.  Use this for your `colors()` function:

```
function colors() 
{
    return cls[Math.floor(Math.random() * clr.length)];
}
```

Comment: Tried that but still not working? Have I missed something else?

Comment: I think the returned value is missing the single quotes when displayed in the colorstop.

Comment: @Cameron: heh, my fault - I focused on the single quotes issue and completely missed the fact that you didn't reference the array.  Oh well ;-) I updated my answer anyway, just to make it a little more complete.